# Operate on command output in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I think the correct operator for executing subshell command in tcsh is the backtick `` ` `` but when I attempt to do a diff on the results of two commands I get an error.  When I direct the information to files first and do a diff on the two files I get exactly what I want but I'd rather just use a single command like:

```
diff `jar -tvf org.jar` `jar -tvf new.jar`
```

What is the correct syntax in tcsh?

Answer (score 6):

You have the correct syntax for a command substitution. But what you need to pass to `diff` are two file *names*, not two file *contents*, which is what you're trying to pass. (What you're actually passing is in fact more complicated, but if you'd written `` diff "`jar -tvf org.jar`" "`jar -tvf new.jar`" ``, you'd be passing two file contents.)

I don't think tcsh has a way to do what you're trying to do, without creating a temporary file. In ksh, bash or zsh, you can do it this way:

```
diff <(jar -tvf org.jar) <(jar -tvf new.jar)
```

Comment: That is a great tip!!

Comment: I tried the double quoting around the backwards quote and diff still is looking for two filename arguments.  I think for bash you need diff < $(jar -tvf org.jar) < $(jar -tvf new.jar) but even this is giving an ambiguous redirect error.  It seems like you can't have two inputs to diff regardless of the shell.  Somehow I need to convert the inputs into temp files or use a different command that compares input streams and not files.

Comment: @Andrew: No, I did mean `<(…)`, it's what bash calls process substitution. It is a way to pass several inputs (or less frequently obtain several outputs) from a program. As far as I know tcsh doesn't have anythinig similar.