# vimdiff to compare output instead of files

Tags: vim, stdout, stdin, vimdiff

I am trying to compare two command output (no files)

```
vimdiff "$(tail /tmp/cachain.pem)" "$(tail /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem)"
```

I tried playing with redirection, pipe, and `vim - -c` but I must be missing something. Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are confusing `$(…)` with `<(…)`. You used the former, which passes the output as *arguments* to `vimdiff`. For example, if the last line of `/path/to/foo` contains `bar bar bar`, then the following command

```
echo $(tail -1 /path/to/foo)
```

is equivalent to

```
echo bar bar bar
```

Instead, you need to use `<(…)`. This is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), and passes the output as a *pseudo-file* to the `vimdiff` command. Hence, use the following.

```
vimdiff <(tail /tmp/cachain.pem) <(tail /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem)
```

This works in `bash` and `zsh`, but apparently there is [no way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5112/18887) to do process substitution in `tcsh`.

Comment: this is only in bash, though

Comment: @simona Works for me in zsh too. Probably csh and tcsh as well.

Comment: @Sparhawk it doesn't work in tcsh

Comment: @simona Thanks for that information; I'm not familiar with tcsh. You might consider putting up an answer that works in tsch. Cheers.

Comment: @Sparhawk apparently there is no way to this in `tcsh` without creating a file https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5111/operate-on-command-output-in-tcsh

Comment: @simona Ah okay. Thanks for that information. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If using gvim, make sure to pass `-f` to avoid `File "/proc/32293/fd/11" no longer available` errors.

Answer (score 0):

In [`fish` shell](http://fishshell.com/), the [`psub` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.4/commands.html#psub) performs process substitution, so your example would be:

```
vimdiff (tail /tmp/cachain.pem | psub) (tail /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem | psub)
```

By the way, I think editing a file in comparison with a specific Git revision of that file is a particularly useful case of process substitution and `vimdiff`.  Define (in `fish` syntax, but easily adaptable to POSIX shell syntax)

```
function vimgitdiff
    vimdiff $argv[1] (git show $argv[2]:$argv[1] | psub)
end
```

then call

```
vimgitdiff path/to/file branch-name
```

to open `Vim` with `path/to/file` as currently in the working tree on the left and as on `branch-name` on the right.