# When to use #!/bin/ksh and #!/bin/sh? Need example

Tags: shell-script, shebang

Also what are the main differences between these two. To execute a script is it necessary to write this at the beginning of script?

Comment: The question is a little all-over-the place, but, based on the "When to use `#!/bin/ksh` and `#!/bin/sh`? … what are the main differences between these …?" parts, I believe that this is a duplicate of [What are the fundamental differences between the mainstream *nix shells?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3320/80216); see also [Which shell should I use – tcsh vs bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/969/80216) and (to a lesser extent) [What's the difference between the terms “Shell” and “Bash”?](http://superuser.com/q/487750/354511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a script executable, the loader will treat the first line as an  interpreter directive and use the specific program to run the script. In this case you are using the [Korn Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell) `#!/bin/ksh` or the [Bourne Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) `#!/bin/sh`.